# How to listen for changes(or get stream) from nested sub collections?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a private chat feature for my app. I have chosen Firestore as my back end and below is how chat threads and messages are structured.

`privateChats` - `chatId1` - `chatId1` - `messageId1, messageId2,...`

`collection` - `document` - `collection` - `documents`

here is the screenshot [image: database structure]

What I am trying to achieve is to get snapshots of every chat threads(chatId1, chatId2,...) with their corresponding message(last document/message was sent) and display like below - refer Chat screen

I have tried something like that
`databaseRef.collection('privateChats').where('chatId', whereIn: chatList).snapshots();`
However streams which are returned from above snapshots only listen for changes on fields where `createdAt` field exists.

Which gives me an only option to get individual snapshot for each chat threads like that
`databaseRef.collection('privateChats').doc('chatId1).collection('chatId1).snapshots();`
`databaseRef.collection('privateChats').doc('chatId2).collection('chatId2).snapshots();` and somehow combine these snapshots into single stream (I don't know how)

So my question is - is there a way to get snapshots of each chat threads with just a single query when given list of chat ids? If not, what could be the solution? Should I come up with different cloud firestore structure?
Thanks
[image: Chats]

Answer (score 3):

what i think you can do is create a doc for each chatRoom ..like say
`databaseRef.collection('privateChats').doc('chatId1+chatId2')`
then both users id1 and id2 can only access the document

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did not really get what you mean. Could you clarify it more?

Comment: yeah, it is currently structured like how you describe, but little different
`databaseRef.collection('privateChats').doc('usertId1-userId2')` in other words `userId1-userId2` represents `chatId1`

Comment: what i'm saying is instead of listening to two streams, you can make it one by creating a document for each chat room (that consist of two users obviously )  like this ` databaseRef.collection('privateChats').doc('chatId1+chatId2') ` where chatId1 is the id of the first user and chatId2 is the id of the second user. i hope you are able to understand now

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is that let's say a user has 10 chat sessions (each session with a different user). I want to able to listen to all 10 chat sessions.

Comment: check out the rxdart package then.it has what you need

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using rxdart `MergeStream` function as **emir adejuwon** suggested

Comment: please check this document https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: if the answer provided was helpul mark it as accepted this will help to another community members

Comment: yes, I am aware of that policy, and I wholeheartedly support it. But the actual answer provided was not helpful. The comment on it was helpful. So I upvoted the only comment